# Programatically switch to an ActivityBar from VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

On my vscode extension, when running a command, I would like to switch to my contributed activity bar

It's there a vscode api for perfoming this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create a View VSC creates for you a command that gives the View the focus.

Execute this command: `viewName.focus`